# ZxingWidget archive error on ios6.0

Tags: zxing, ios6

I try to archive the ZxingWedget Demo,scanTest. compile is ok. it can run on the simulator.
but it can not archive completely on ios6.0.

this is the error:

```
Stripping /Users/ganguo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ScanTest-gadjcaxemklyqpcxsvmiorzakfhu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ScanTest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ZXingWidget.build/Release-iphoneos/ZXingWidget.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libZXingWidget.a
    cd /Users/ganguo/objc/lib/zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget
    setenv PATH "/Applications/app/Xcode45-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/app/Xcode45-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/app/Xcode45-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -S /Users/ganguo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ScanTest-gadjcaxemklyqpcxsvmiorzakfhu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ScanTest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ZXingWidget.build/Release-iphoneos/ZXingWidget.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libZXingWidget.a

0  0x10eaf75f0  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x10eb5ed12  ld::tool::FunctionStartsAtom<arm>::encode() const + 594
2  0x10eb4d05b  ld::tool::OutputFile::updateLINKEDITAddresses(ld::Internal&) + 251
3  0x10eb483b8  ld::tool::OutputFile::write(ld::Internal&) + 136
4  0x10eaf7c5f  main + 1263
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/strip.7jH8OR-2012-07-16-113649.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (addr != badAddress), function encode, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-134.5/src/ld/LinkEdit.hpp, line 1289.
/Applications/app/Xcode45-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip: internal link edit command failed
Command /Applications/app/Xcode45-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I filed the bug (12176840) with Apple for this problem today.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean and try again. If it still fails, file a bug with Apple. This is an xcode/toolchain bug (in prerelease software).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the zxing library doesn't support the armv7 architecture yet. I would love to be wrong, though...