# Build failed - symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: zxing, xcode4.5, armv7, armv6

I am using the library ZXingWidget, CocoaTouchBarcodes and I have an error when i try to build my project, it worked before Xcode 4.5 but now it trashes.

If i try with an armv6 architecture only it works but with armv7 it doesn't work...

Here the error log :

---

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIControl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIDickBar in UIDickBar.o
  "_UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext", referenced from:
      -[MBProgressHUD drawRect:] in MBProgressHUD.o
      -[MBRoundProgressView drawRect:] in MBProgressHUD.o
      -[RoundedUITableViewMask drawRect:] in RoundedUITableView.o
      -[GradientButton drawRect:] in GradientButton.o
      -[UIDickBar drawRect:] in UIDickBar.o
      -[Radar drawRect:] in Radar.o
      -[RadarViewPortView drawRect:] in RadarViewPortView.o
      ...

(...)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

I have already searched on those links but they don't work for me.

- [Linking Error in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287915/linking-error-in-xcode)
- [ZxingWidget archive error on ios6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980618/zxingwidget-archive-error-on-ios6-0)
- [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)
- [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7, ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 - what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235993/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architectu)